# Pandas mean pivot table contains NaN values even though data was filled prior to aggregating

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, kaggle

I am having a hard time making sense of this result.

I am working with the Titanic dataset from kaggle, which lists survivorship data from the Titanic. Many of the entries in the "Cabin" column are NaN, so I fill those with "Z", a dummy variable. I am only interested in the Cabin letter, so I create a new column by slicing the first character of the string. I then group by "Sex" and "Cabin_letter" and calculate the mean of survivorship by gender in each cabin class. Here is my code:

```
print(train["Cabin"].isnull().sum())
print(train["Sex"].isnull().sum())
print(train["Survived"].isnull().sum())
train["Cabin"].fillna(value="Z", inplace=True)
print(train["Cabin"].isnull().sum())
train["cabin_letter"] = train["Cabin"].str.slice(0,1)
print(train["cabin_letter"].isnull().sum())
train.pivot_table(values = 'Survived', index='Sex', columns='cabin_letter', aggfunc=np.mean)

women_T = train["cabin_letter"].loc[train["Sex"]=="female"]
print(women_T.isnull().any())
```

I am printing the sum of NaN values in each Series to make sure it is not coming from elsewhere, and that the replacement takes place as expected. Only the Cabin column contains NaNs. Here is the output:

```
687

0

0

0

0

cabin_letter    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   T   Z

Sex
                                    
female  1.000000    1.0 0.888889    1.000000    0.933333    1.000   0.5 NaN 0.654378

male    0.428571    0.4 0.343750    0.466667    0.588235    0.375   NaN 0.0 0.136170

False
```

I can see that the replacement is working, as there are no "Z" values by default. Why are there NaNs in the "G" and "T" columns?

For what it is worth, I have looked at other SO posts pertaining to similar issues, such as this one: [Pandas Dataframe nan values not replacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50685107/pandas-dataframe-nan-values-not-replacing)

But none that I have looked at have seemed to address this.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an indication that there are no values that correspond to those combinations (i.e. no females in cabin T or males in cabin G).

You should be able to confirm with `train[train.Cabin == 'T'].Sex.value_counts()`

Here's a toy example to illustrate following the form of your data:

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'sex': list('mfmfmfm'), 
                    'survived': [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], 
                    'cabin': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd']})
dat
dat.pivot_table(values = 'survived', index='sex', columns = 'cabin', aggfunc=np.mean)
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, just figured it out. I would have expected it to give a 0 if there were no values, but I guess I just need to make that replacement explicitly.